# Let $Y$ be a path connected subset of a topological space $X$ and $Z = Y \cup \{p\}$ where $p$ is a boundary point of $Y$. Show $Z$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $Y$ be a path connected subset of a topological space $X$ and $Z = Y \cup \{p\}$ where $p$ is a boundary point of $Y$. Show $Z$ is path connected.

---

I'm having trouble writing up a rigorous proof of this. I'm assuming exists a point $x$ such that there is no path from $p$ to $x$ but having trouble coming up with a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. The origin is a boundary point of the graph of $y = \sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ but there is no path connecting it to any other point.